# Unable to open database file - sqlite3?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

When I am trying to sqlite database in iPhone I got one error..

"Unable to open database file"

So anyone please tell me what are the main causes for this error??

Regards,
Syam

Comment: I could give you the obvious reason...that it cannot open the file...but that would be too obvious. Perhaps you can give us some background as to on which platform it was created, and such you know. Provide more details.

Comment: I am using FMDB wrapper for i Phone. I am trying access the call_history.db from a jail broken iphone. I was able to open the database file and executes select query successfully. But when I tried to modify the db then I got this error. The permission mode for the file set by "chmod 666 call_history.db" command. But I still getting this error..Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are using the correct path by logging the file path and check the file manually.
2. Check whether the sqlite file is a proper by checking the file size. It should not be 0kb.